# Wordpress, Japanese sentence being displayed from right to the left

Tags: wordpress, unicode, internationalization

I'm using Wordpress 3.2.1. In the back-end (admin area) everything is in English but I want to display some Japanese in the front-end.

When editing a post I type Japanese and everything looks ok in the editor but once I save it and view the page it shows the text from right to left.

How can I avoid this behavior and have Japanese displayed from left to right.

Comment: Why do you want to show Japanese from right to left? Traditional style goes from right to left but also goes from top to bottom. The other way is occidental style which is left to right.

Comment: no, i want to show from left to right. but currentyly it show from right to left. is it encoding problem and how to fixed it?

Comment: I see now, let me edit the question because it's hard to understand the way it's now and maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's an encoding problem but rather something to do with the `css`, if you have your site online mind giving a link? Otherwise check your style-sheets taking into account the following: http://codex.wordpress.org/Right_to_Left_Language_Support

Comment: On the top of the website you have the following:
`<html dir="rtl" lang="fa">`, that `rtl` means `right to left`, remove it so it look like this: `<html lang="fa">`.

Comment: which file is it?
i try to change it using firebug and it looks ok.
i need to find which file to change.
is it style.css?
anyway thanks for ur help

Comment: Since it's wordpress you have to edit the `header.php` of the theme you're using. I believe you have to go to `Appearance > Themes > Editor` and then choose `header.php`. The other option is, if you have access to the files through ftp then download the `header.php` from your current theme folder, edit what I said before and re-upload to the same folder.

Comment: wow. it works. thanks for ur help.
thank you very much.
sorry for disturbing you because i'm still new in website development

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug in called polylang for wordpress that can solve your problems :  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/